# Div - "fill the rest of the line"

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a div that will automatically fill the rest of the space on the page. Here is an example (not working properly):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbGLYX

`#autoWidth` should get the width depending on the content, and `#fullWidth` should fill the rest of the available space without creating a new line space.

As you see, there is `#autoWidth` and `#fullWidth`. I added float:left to both, to make them on the same line, however after styling the `#fullWidth` div (that needs to fill the remaining space on the same line with `#autoWidth`) it automatically created a second line.

There are other issues as well, for instance, the `background-color` property is not working as it should, for the container div.

I believe these are all connected issues with my question, and would appreciate a good solution.

PS - Looking for a CSS-only solution. As little hack as possible.

Comment: it's not a duplicate - the provided solution does not work for this case.

Comment: Use flex. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYGJmL

Comment: I second that this is not a duplicate. That answer is 3 years old and CSS Flexbox is the correct 'modern' solution for this issue.

Comment: Float:left; on your container fixes the background but it's not an ideal solution. I second the flex box method

Comment: An alternative to `flex` is to use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`, where `width:100%` means "the rest of the *available* space" (this is also supported in IE8+). Updated example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbyGLX